# Permalink not working

Tags: permalinks

The address of my WordPress site is something like: http://mycompany.com/personnel/myname.

The installation folder is: **/www/personnel/myname**.

When I change Permalink to **Post name**, it requires me to create an *.htaccess* file with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /personnel/myname/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /personnel/myname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**I only have the write permission to the folder /personnel/myname/ and not to the root.** Thus I created the required .htaccess file in there, but then obtained 404 error when accessing.

Hope somebody can help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server?

Comment: Hi @Milo. Using phpinfo() I see that mod_rewrite is one of the Loaded Modules, so it is already enabled.

Comment: is your server configured to parse .htaccess files in the directory it's in? do you get a WordPress 404, or a server 404?

Comment: Hi @Milo. Sorry for the late reply. How to know if the server is configured for that? It's a server 404 (404 Not found. The requested URL was not found on this server). Thanks.